# Is it haram to break my fast in my furry suit?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

Assalamu Alaykum,

One of my favorite hobbies is being a furry. I currently own a rabbit, squirrel, and fox suits. I avoid any pig suits alhamdulilah. My question is would breaking my fast in my furry suit nullify my fast? I would like to combine my passions. Does it matter which animal it is? I am wearing underwear in the suit.

Jazakum Allahu Khayran

Comment: Is this some kind of a troll?

Answer (score -1):

Breaking your fast during the day is haram. However, if you are talking about breaking your fast during the Maghreb Adthan, then I do not think what you're wearing matters. There is not anything I am aware of that makes what you wear matter. I think even pig suits should be fine (unless you eat your pig suit)